# What are the implications of lethal use of military technology developed by industrial engineers with the use of data science?

Tags: beginner, data-engineering

I’m currently in my first year of collage in engineering and I was wondering about the implications of the use of technology in military applications, with the combination of data science and industrial engineering, (which is the major I chose) used in lethal systems, such as armed drones or autonomous weapons systems, looking for opinions of anyone who has any experience in this topic.

Comment: opinion-based, suggest to close.